# C# Setting Item Property State

Tags: c#, interface, attributes, tracking

I would like to set a property called "Current" which give me the opportunity to keep track of which item I'm working with. Here's my class Volume:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3 {
class Volume : Interface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Volume()
    {

    }
 }
```

My interface called: "Interface"

```
namespace ConsoleApp3{
class Interface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }
}
```

And my RootList Class:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3{
class RootList<T> : List<T> where T : Interface, new()
{
    private int _index;
    private int _id;
    public RootList()
    {

    }

    public T First
    {
        get => this[0];
        set => this[0] = value;
    }

    public T Last
    {
        get => this[this.Count - 1];
        set => this[this.Count - 1] = value;
    }
  public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FirstOrDefault(tTemp => tTemp.IsCurrent == true);
        }
        set
        {
            this.RmCurrent();
            int _index = this.IndexOf(value);
            this[_index].IsCurrent = true;
        }
    }

    public T this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FirstOrDefault(tTemp => tTemp.Name == name);
        }
    }
   private void RmCurrent()
    {
        var _iscurrent = this.Where(v => v.IsCurrent = true);
        foreach (var item in _iscurrent)
        {
            item.IsCurrent = false;
        }
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        this.Add(new T());
        this.RmCurrent();
        this.Last.IsCurrent = true;
    }
}
```

}

I'm using the "IsCurrent" property to track my items: my item has the "Current" state if the "IsCurrent" property is "true". Only one item can me the "Current" one at the same time.
My "Current" method doesn't work. For exmaple:

```
        VolumeList.Add();
        VolumeList.Last.Name = "test_0";
        VolumeList.Add();
        VolumeList.Last.Name = "test_1";
        VolumeList.Add();
        VolumeList.Last.Name = "test_2";
```

In this case, my Current item is the Last one "test_2".
If I do that:

```
           VolumeList.Current = VolumeList[1];
```

I have two Current items VolumeList[0] and VolumeList[1]. Not only VolumeList[1].
As you can see, I also have a string indexer in my RootList so it has to work with int indexer and string indexer.
Do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Best regards,

Comment: Seems more to me like it's the RootList's job to remember the current item, not the item itself to remember whether it's current. Looking up which item is current every time is horrendous. Move the concept of Current T into RootList

Comment: @Caius Jard That's true! Can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would not search for an item which is current in `private void RmCurrent()`

I would only do

```cs
private void RmCurrent()
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            item.IsCurrent = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make the RootList track current:

```
public class RootList<T> : List<T> where T : Interface, new()
{
    public T Current { get; private set; }

    public T First
    {
        get => Current = this[0]; 
        set => Current = this[0] = value;
    }

    public T Last
    {
        get => Current = this[this.Count - 1];
        set => Current = this[this.Count - 1] = value;
    }

    public T this[string name]
    {
        //what if there is no such name? what do you want current to be? 
        //if it should not change, break this lambda up using a temp var 
        //that you do not assign to current if it is null

        get => Current = this.FirstOrDefault(tTemp => tTemp.Name == name); 
    }

    public void Add() //careful, the List<T> you inherit from also has an Add(T), and so calling myList.Add(something) it won't set the current item
    {
        Current = new T();
        this.Add(Current);
    }
}
```

So what's going on ?

Assignments in C# return, as a value, the value that was assigned. It means that this:

```
myString = "hello";
```

returns "hello". It can be used in another assignment:

```
myString2 = (myString = "hello");
```

Both the strings are "hello";

Single line lambdas must be a value, so this:

```
get => Current = this[0];
```

Assigns the Current to be the first item in the list and then gives the first item in the list to the get, to be returned. It's like saying:

```
get {
  Current = this[0];
  return Current;
}
```

Your Current is now the first item in the list, just because you accessed the First property

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand what you mean now. First ans Last won't set my Current but you learnt me a lot. I need to set Current manually like: myList.Current = myList["name"]; or myList.Current = myList[index]. Do you know how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Setting current manually can be done too.. The main problem with the whole question is that you haven't really ever specified what operations affect the Current and what don't. So far, from this comment you've said "First and Last don't" and "it is set manually" but your "Add" automatically sets it, so *as a specification of what is needed, it isn't very complete/accurate*. Write a better specification and we can help more

Comment: Of course I understand. My "Add" was to try something I was thinking about but it si not important. You show me how to track it directly from the RootList and I learnt a lot (I didn't know it was possible). So, what I need now is to set manually the Current by name or index. This has to be manage by the RootList as recommanded by yourself. First and Last just help me to navigate in my list. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't set the Current by accessing an int index because `List<T>` already has a `public T this[int index]` and you can't override it. You can hide it, by providing your own `public new T this[int index]` and your version will be used if the object is used as a RootList, but not as a List (for example `List<X> x = new RootList<X>` will use List's `this[int]` not yours).. I think rather than descending from List<T> you should write a class that implements IList<T> in its own right if you want this. It can use a List internally and proxy to it

Comment: I understood what you said, but I'm not sure to be able to code it for the moment. Is it possible to simply set the Curren by accessing with the string Name which of course as to be unique? If not, can you show me how to code my own class? (I know I'm asking a lot...)

Comment: I already did that in the answer? It has a large comment block above it recommending you to think about what you want to happen if the name is not found